# multiple value insert using saveField function or other function in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I insert multiple values into my database using saveField function. Here is my code.

```
$this->Fuel->saveField(
    'device_id',    $int_fuel_func[0],
    'func_code',    $int_fuel_func[1],
    'device_data',  $int_fuel_func[2]
);
```

It's not a form value. Value automatically insert when the page is refreshed.

It's only inserts first value `'device_id', $int_fuel_func[0],`. Other two values are not insert into my database. Any one suggest me how to insert these values.

Thanks in advance

Cake version 2.7.5

Comment: first of all try debug($fuel_func); and see the result..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My id is not auto Increment it is defined as varchar. Time is not include there also. I got my answer. I use it and it works.

```
$this->Fuel->set(
    array(
        'device_id'   => $int_fuel_value[0],
        'func_code'   => $int_fuel_value[1],
        'device_data' => $int_fuel_value[2]
    )
);
$this->Fuel->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

`saveField` function is only for updating one field! use `updateAll` and pass an array to it :

```
$this->Fuel->updateAll(
    array(
        'device_id',    $int_fuel_func[0],
        'func_code',    $int_fuel_func[1],
        'device_data',  $int_fuel_func[2]
    ),
    array('Fuel.id' => 234) // conditions for the Fuel you want to update   
);
```

Answer (score 1):

*You can simply do this as well.*

```
$data = array(
    'device_id'   => $int_fuel_value[0],
    'func_code'   => $int_fuel_value[1],
    'device_data' => $int_fuel_value[2]
  );

$this->Fuel->save($data);
```

Also try this blog tutorial ([cakephp blog tutorial](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html)) if you haven't been there before to be more familiar with these things.